# linear regression model with lagging effect/interaction

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I want to create a model such as below, with numeric continuous data:

`revenue~variable+variable2+variable3`

My data has around 1000 observations, with 5 variables altogether which are the above mentioned dependent variable and 3 independent variables, together with the date. Each row represents a single day. I want to build the model such that not only do the independent variables effect the dependent variable (revenue), but also the independent variables from previous days. I want the effect from previous days to decrease over time. So for example, yesterdays independent variables would have a larger effect on the revenue todaythan the day before etc.... all the way to the 100th previous day.

To make it more clear, this is an advertising model looking at how an individual seeing a type of advert (independent variables are types of TV advert) impacts the revenue, with adverts seen longer away being less likely to cause an action and purchase.

In other words, perhaps adding decay terms to the model.

Comment: I would look at [forecasting with lagged predictors](https://otexts.com/fpp3/lagged-predictors.html) and [Vector Autoregression](https://otexts.com/fpp2/VAR.html)

Comment: Consider using an [adstock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertising_adstock) transformation on your variables to capture diminishing impact of ad rather than introducing lots of variables. The transformation would be easier than trying to enforce n constraints.

Comment: This question would be better on cross-validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it is about creating/picking an algorithm to use rather than how to get your code working.

Comment: Depending on the decay rate you expect, with daily data, I'd remove day of week effect, using a seven day moving total (requires apt calculation at decomposition). Then do lag&decay transformations on the rolled data. If it were display ads then no problem (decay rate is expected to be short), but if ads are branded TV advertising your client expect to see a some residual effect lasting maybe 2/3 weeks. Daily data also hard to pin point when exact lag starts, you'd have to do this Y = b1*X1 + 0.5*X1_lag1 + 0.2*X1_lag2. Lags and decay covered, next up is factor in diminishing returns or R&F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work in econometrics. I use this

```
df <- data.frame(X1=(seq(1,10,by=1))) 

library(dplyr)
df <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(X1_lag1 = dplyr::lag(X1, n = 1, default = NA))
df

> df
   X1 X1_lag1
1   1      NA
2   2       1
3   3       2
4   4       3
5   5       4
6   6       5
7   7       6
8   8       7
9   9       8
10 10       9
```

whereby df is dataframe, and X1 is the variable you want to lag, and X1_lag1 is the new lagged variable.
You can put a decay on the 0.5*X1_lag1 on the lagged variable, create permutations. In SAS I can put a coefficient on the decay factor but it gets very messy. I rather create multiple permutations of decay and see which has best fit.